# SwiftUI Array w/ OpenWeatherMap

Tags: swift, openweathermap

I have hourly forecast in my SwiftUI Weather App but in my struct, it needs an array for the weather hourly data. Earlier it was conformed to string. I made it conform to array but I get the error `Reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>`.

Struct:

```swift
struct OneCall: Decodable {
    let lat, lon: Double
    let timezone : String
    let timezone_offset : Int
    let current: CurrentResponse
    let hourly: HourlyResponse

    struct HourlyResponse: Decodable{
        var hourly: Array //Error
    }
}
```

I've tried using `<Any>` but that didn't work

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Array of what? In swift you cannot say just Array, it is not Objective-C.

Comment: @Asperi an array of Weather Hourly Data

Comment: Is it an array of String? If so, it should be *var hourly: [String]* . Otherwise, you should map it by creating a new decodable struct.

Comment: You can't have something "undefined that could be anything", like "Any", or "Array". The compiler can't tell how to decode that. If it's an array of String, `var hourly: [String]`. But without knowing the JSON/Doc, it's hard to say what it should be in reality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `hourly` is actually an array of the `CurrentResponse` struct minus the keys `sunrise` and `sunset`.

If you use those make them optional

```
let sunrise: Date?
let sunset: Date?
```

and declare `hourly` in **OneCall**

```
let hourly: [CurrentResponse]
```

or this syntax with regard to the error message

```
let hourly: Array<CurrentResponse>
```

the `HourlyResponse` struct is not needed.

---

`Any` is not supported by `Codable` at all.